# Migrating a windows 8 partition into vmware on ubuntu

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, vmware

So currently, on my laptop, I have ubuntu 14.10 and windows 8 installed, and I dual boot (99% of the time, into the ubuntu partition).

I was wondering if there's a way to "move" the windows 8 partition into vmware, so I don't have to shut down my ubuntu instance if I need to run something on windows?

Even better, is it possible to run the windows 8 partition using vmware? It would be nice if the next time I boot into the windows partition, the changes I made to it while on vmware persists..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a good way to link them but you can convert your Windows Partition to a VHD by following this guide. http://www.howtogeek.com/213145/how-to%C2%A0convert-a-physical-windows-or-linux-pc-to-a-virtual-machine/